# Multilingual app tool kit resource string reference warning in android and iOS projects

Tags: android, xamarin.android, multilingual-app-toolkit

I have added multilingual toolkit for my Android & iOS projects. wherever the resource string being referred we are getting the below error.

> Transparent method 'Method1()' references security critical method 'AppResource.Not_Recognized.get()'.  In order for this reference to be allowed under the security transparency rules, either 'Method1()' must become security critical or safe-critical, or 'AppResource.Not_Recognized.get()' become security safe-critical or transparent.

We are having so many strings and are being referred in multiple places so adding the security critical or safe-critical attributes in all the places is not possible.

Is there any option to make the complete project as security critical or safe-critical or any other option to fix this issue.

Comment: You could check the link about the cause and how to fix it.https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/code-quality/ca2140?view=vs-2019

Answer (score 0):

If your project compiles, and it probably does, you can ignore this type of messages in Xamarin, right now I can't provide you with the link where it is described why, but I have already investigated problems like this before and came to conclusion that it is safe.